# TypeError: axios.get is not a function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios, jestjs

Not sure why I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: axios.get is not a function

    4 |
    5 | export const getTotalPayout = async (userId: string) => {
  > 6 |   const response = await axios.get(`${endpoint}get-total-payout`, { params: userId });
    7 |   return response.data;
    8 | };
    9 |
```

**My service:**

```
import * as axios from 'axios';

const endpoint = '/api/pool/';

export const getTotalPayout = async (userId: string) => {
  const response = await axios.get(`${endpoint}get-total-payout`, { params: userId });
  return response.data;
};
```

**My jest test:**

```
// import mockAxios from 'axios';
import { getTotalPayout } from './LiquidityPool';

const userId = 'foo';

describe('Pool API', () => {
  it('getTotalPayout is called and returns the total_payout for the user', async () => {
    // mockAxios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
    //   Promise.resolve({
    //     data: {
    //       total_payout: 100.21,
    //     },
    //   });
    // });

    const response = await getTotalPayout(userId);
    console.log('response', response);
  });
});
```

**In the src/__mocks__/axios.js I have this:**

```
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty
const mockNoop = () => new Promise(() => {});

export default {
  get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: { total_payout: 100.21 }})),
  default: mockNoop,
  post: mockNoop,
  put: mockNoop,
  delete: mockNoop,
  patch: mockNoop
};
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please look at: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Syntax)

As mentoined there, you need a value to collect the `default export` and the rest as `X`. In this case you could:

```
import axios, * as others from 'axios';
```

X being `others` here.

Instead of

```
import * as axios from 'axios';
```

Assumption: `... from 'axios'` is referring to your jest mock.

Answer (score 12):

Use import as `import Axios from "axios";` instead of `import { Axios } from "axios";`

Comment: lower case a with this format worked for me

`import axios from "axios"`

Answer (score 2):

You have `import * as axios from 'axios';`. In this case `axios` is *not a default export*. Your mock assumes it is so:

```
export default {
  get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: { total_payout: 100.21 }})),
  default: mockNoop,
  post: mockNoop,
  put: mockNoop,
  delete: mockNoop,
  patch: mockNoop
};
```

## Fix

Remove the default export and replace your mock structure to map the export structure of axios as you are using it.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more, so instead of a default export, just export the `{}` object? Or a named export? Also I thought I was using that structure of axios, only the `get` matters atm.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import axios like this:

```js
import axios, * as others from 'axios';
```