# in my js file with axios when i try to post some test data to firebase, i am getting some error

Tags: reactjs, axios

when I tried to post some random data to firebase through axios from the js file, the error shown is given below.

```
 _axios_order__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.post is not a function.
```

the code is

```
//all import statements including axios and there is an axios file and it contains an axios baseURL.And the class definition.

purchasecontinueHandler=()=>{
    const order={
        ingredients:this.state.ingredient,
        price:this.state.burgerprice,
    }
    axios.post('/orders.json',order)
    .then(response => console.log(response))
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that imports axios?

Comment: `axios` isn't what you think it is. Please include the imports

Comment: Without seeing the import I can't say its a duplicate, but maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52396724/typeerror-axios-get-is-not-a-function/52397838

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this was my mistaken code, here I exported the 'instance' with a new method, unfortunately, that was not required.

import axios from 'axios';
const intsance=axios.create({
    baseURL:'https://burger-d4f0a.firebaseio.com/'
}); 
export default new intsance();
```

just define as

```
import axios from 'axios';
const intsance=axios.create({
    baseURL:'https://burger-d4f0a.firebaseio.com/'
}); 
 export default intsance;
```