# Uncaught TypeError: axios.get(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, axios, discord.js

when I try to use get from axios, it just does not get anything.

```
bot.on("message", async function(message) {
    try {
        if (message.author == bot.user) return;
        if (message.channel.type == "dm" || message.channel.type == "group") {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
            if (!message.channel.typing) {
                message.channel.startTyping();
                setTimeout(function() {
                    const URI = "http://api.brainshop.ai/get?bid=&key=&uid=[uid]&msg=[msg]";
                    const encodedURI = encodeURI(URI);
                    axios.get(encodedURI)
                        .then(async response => {
                            var data = response
                            message.reply(data)
                        });
                    message.channel.stopTyping();
                }, 5000);
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
});
```

I have the correct URL, I just took out part of it.

Comment: must be a inclusion error. can you share the script url? and is this just javascript or some framework or library with which you are working?

Comment: This appears to be discord.js @AdisonMasih

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: axios.get is not a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52396724/typeerror-axios-get-is-not-a-function)

Comment: "took out part of it" what do you mean by that? did you not include the whole script url? and are you getting any 404 errors in the console?

Comment: No. this is the original URL
`http://api.brainshop.ai/get?bid=161231&key=[key redacted]&uid=[uid]&msg=[msg]`

Comment: Im trying to make a discord AI bot

Comment: instead of your desired target can you specify the exact problem?

Comment: it says "Uncaught TypeError: axios.get(...) is not a function".

Comment: Did you add `const axios = require('axios');` if you use package manager or `window.axios.get(...)` if you use compiled file and have `window` available?

Comment: it says `axios.get(...)` not `axios.get` meaning you probably did `axios.get(...) (function () {} )()` or something like that. Be sure to put a semi-colon (`;`) after every `axios.get`